# Analysis and Compact intervals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

Let $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ Then $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $x_1,x_2$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ such that $|x_1-x_2|<\epsilon$

I would like hints on this particular problem, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_1=a$ and $c=a+\epsilon /2$

If $c\in [a,b]$ then let $x_2=c$

Otherwise $c>b$ so you may choose $x_2=b$

In both cases you  have $|x_1-x_2|<\epsilon$

Comment: @topologicalmagician  this is the case where $b<c=a+\epsilon /2$ so $b-a <c-a<\epsilon /2$